# At update sql record in java disappear backslash

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

When i `INSERT` image path, backslash remain in place `C:\Users\COMP\Desktop\Image.png`. But if i `UPDATE` sql record the same code for path, backslash disappears `C:UsersCOMPDesktopImage.png`

```
query = "UPDATE battle SET name = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"', Image = '"+jTextField1.getText()+"' WHERE name = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"' ;";
```

But INSERT i make differently

```
protected void insertW(String s1, String s2) query = "INSERT INTO db.work (db.work .name, db.work .Image) VALUES (?,?);";
```

and through insertW convey the value of the field, `insertW(jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText());`

How to fix it?

```
JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
        jTextField1.setText(filename);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Please provide more code snippets. Show us, where you do the INSERT and UPDATE.

Comment: Also let us know which version of SQL you are using, as there may be nuances about how each database handles backslashes and escaping.

Comment: I make it in HeidiSQL last version.

Answer (score 1):

When doing the insert, you're using prepared statements - which is good as they are stored in the database in the way they come.

But when doing the update, you're set the values as 'plain string', no matter what. This should be avoided as this is also a high security risk (SQL injection). Try to do the update as you do the insert, via prepared statements. This link to JDBC basics might help you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html